# Upsampling using 3d_transposed_convolution layers

Tags: tensorflow, transpose, convolution, deconvolution

Suppose I have a 4D tensor `x` from a previous layer with shape `[2, 2, 7, 7, 64]` where `batch = 2`, `depth = 2`, `height = 7`, `width = 7`, and `in_channels = 64`.

And I'd like to upsample it to a tensor with shape `[2, 4, 14, 14, 32]`. 
Maybe next steps are transferring it with shape like `[2, 8, 28, 28, 16]` and `[2, 16, 112, 112, 1]` and so on.

I'm new to Tensorflow and I know that the implementations of transposed convolution between CAFFE and Tensorflow are different. I mean, in CAFFE, you can define the size of output by changing the strides of kernel. However, it's more complicated in tensorflow.

So how can I do that with `tf.layers.conv3d_transpose` or `tf.nn.conv3d_transpose`?

Would anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the upsampling with both [tf.layers.conv3d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv3d_transpose) and [tf.nn.conv3d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d_transpose).

Lets consider your input tensor as:

```
input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (2, 2, 7, 7, 64)) # batch, depth, height, width, in_channels
```

With `tf.nn.conv3d_transpose` we need to take care of the creation of the variables (weights and bias):

```
def conv3d_transpose(name, l_input, w, b, output_shape, stride=1):
    transp_conv = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(l_input, w, output_shape, strides=[1, stride, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
    return tf.nn.bias_add(transp_conv, b, name=name)

# Create variables for the operation
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):  
    # weights will have the shape [depth, height, width, output_channels, in_channels]
    weights = tf.get_variable(name='w_transp_conv', shape=[3, 3, 3, 32, 64])
    bias = tf.get_variable(name='b_transp_conv', shape=[32]) 

t_conv_layer = conv3d_transpose('t_conv_layer', input_layer, weights, bias,
                                output_shape=[2, 4, 14, 14, 32], stride=2)
print(t_conv_layer) 
# Tensor("t_conv_layer:0", shape=(2, 4, 14, 14, 32), dtype=float32)
```

With `tf.layers.conv3d_transpose`, which will take care of the creation of both weights and bias, we use the same input tensor `input_layer`:

```
t_conv_layer2 = tf.layers.conv3d_transpose(input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[3, 3, 3],
                                           strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='SAME', name='t_conv_layer2')
print(t_conv_layer2)  
# Tensor("t_conv_layer2/Reshape_1:0", shape=(2, 4, 14, 14, 32), dtype=float32)
```

To get the other upsampled tensors you can repeat this procedure by changing the strides as you need:

Example with tf.layers.conv3d_transpose:

```
t_conv_layer3 = tf.layers.conv3d_transpose(t_conv_layer2, filters=16, kernel_size=[3, 3, 3],
                                           strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='SAME', name='t_conv_layer3')
t_conv_layer4 = tf.layers.conv3d_transpose(t_conv_layer3, filters=8, kernel_size=[3, 3, 3], 
                                           strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='SAME',   name='t_conv_layer4')
t_conv_layer5 = tf.layers.conv3d_transpose(t_conv_layer4, filters=1, kernel_size=[3, 3, 3], 
                                           strides=(1, 2, 2), padding='SAME', name='t_conv_layer5')
print(t_conv_layer5)
# Tensor("t_conv_layer5/Reshape_1:0", shape=(2, 16, 112, 112, 1), dtype=float32)
```

**Note:** since tf.nn.conv3d_transpose is actually the gradient of tf.nn.conv3d, you can make sure that the variable `output_shape` is correct, by considering the forward operation with tf.nn.conv3d.

```
def print_expected(weights, shape, stride=1):
    output = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    expected_layer = tf.nn.conv3d(output, weights, strides=[1, stride, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
    print("Expected shape of input layer when considering the output shape ({} and stride {}): {}".format(shape, stride, expected_layer.get_shape()))
```

Therefore, to produce a transposed convolution with shape [2, 4, 14, 14, 32], we can check, for example, strides 1 and 2:

```
print_expected(weights, shape=[2, 4, 14, 14, 32], stride=1) 
print_expected(weights, shape=[2, 4, 14, 14, 32], stride=2)
```

which prints and confirms that the second option (using stride 2) is the right one to produce a tensor with our desired shape:

```
Expected shape of input layer when considering the output shape ([2, 4, 14, 14, 32] and stride 1): (2, 4, 14, 14, 64)
Expected shape of input layer when considering the output shape ([2, 4, 14, 14, 32] and stride 2): (2, 2, 7, 7, 64)
```